# Calling external API (AWS EC2 server) from Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, firebase, request-promise

Anyone can help me out of this?..

I'm using request-promise to call an API from AWS  in firebase functions
below is the code im using, and the image is the output.

I'm wondering why it returns `statuscode 400` with the expected output from the API (AWS) that I'm calling

Output of this code:
[image]

```js
exports.testregisterstep1 = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

  var rp = require("request-promise");


    var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'http://1X.XXX.122.XXX:1000/api/katz/step1',
    formData: {
        first_name: 'fname',
        last_name: 'lname',
        email: 'emailfnam@gmail.com',
        mobile: '0909090909',
        address: 'address City',
        id: 1
        
    },
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'x-auth-token': 'eyJh3DV303g3eKSrE' 
    },
      resolveWithFullResponse: true,
    json: true
};
 
rp(options)
    .then(function(body) {
    res.send("Request OK: " + body);
})
    .catch(function (err) {
        res.send(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: What exactly is returning status 400?  The call to AWS, or the call to Cloud Functions?  How you are invoking this function?

Comment: What is your Firebase pricing plan? The free "Spark" plan? Note that the free "Spark" plan "allows outbound network requests only to Google-owned services". See https://firebase.google.com/pricing/ (hover your mouse on the question mark situated after the "Cloud Functions" title). You need to be on the "Flame" or "Blaze" pricing plan.

Comment: Actually the AWS is fine, it just return response as expected but Google Cloud function only return a response a weird, like always saying error but it actually working between Google Cloud Functin and AWS.

Comment: im currently subscribed Flame Plan